# C# -Termination in Aggregate( )

Tags: c#, extension-methods

From  the following simulation

```
int[] amountWithdrawal = { 10, 20, 30, 140, 50, 70 };

amountWithdrawal.Aggregate(100, (balance, withdrawal) => 
{
  Console.WriteLine("balance :{0},Withdrawal:{1}", balance, withdrawal);
 if (balance >= withdrawal)
 {
   return balance - withdrawal;
 }
 else return balance;
 }
);
```

I want to terminate the Aggregation `when  the balance is less than the withdrawal`.But my code travels the entire array.How to terminate it?

Comment: Sorry for deviating from Topic... When I copy this code and paste in my VS 2005... I get Syntax error at various places... But I could see this code is working for you... Am I missing something... I use VS 2005 and .NET 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you want an `Accumulate` method which yields a new sequence of accumulated values, instead of a scalar. Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> SequenceAggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
{
    TAccumulate current = seed;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        current = func(current, item);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

Then you could apply `TakeWhile`:

```
int[] amountWithdrawal = { 10, 20, 30, 140, 50, 70 };

var query = amountWithdrawal.SequenceAggregate(100, (balance, withdrawal) => 
{
  Console.WriteLine("balance :{0},Withdrawal:{1}", balance, withdrawal);
  return balance - withdrawal;
}).TakeWhile (balance => balance >= 0);
```

I could have sworn there was something like this in normal LINQ to Objects, but I can't find it at the moment...

Comment: you cant TakeWhile on a scalar value, Jon ;p

Comment: Doh. Got confused with an "aggregate and return new value as series" operator, whose name I currently forget.

Comment: Fixed using a new operator... I'm still hoping there's an existing operator somewhere...

Comment: In the F#-library this function is called 'scan' (Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq.scan). I don't believe there's an implementation in the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Aggregate` as normal, then use `Where` to omit negative balances.

BTW, using functions with side effects (such as `Console.WriteLine`) inside a LINQ method is bad practice. You're better off doing all of the LINQ aggregation and filtering first, then writing a `foreach` loop to print to the console.

Comment: I dont think this is the answer the OP is looking for. He wants to check for a negative balance, not omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace aggregate with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `TakeWhile().Aggregate()` and check the balance in the take while predicate.

Comment: The balance is only present *after* the aggregation though - which is why I've placed TakeWhile after it.

Comment: ... but as you point out, Aggregate is going to return a scalar anyway. Hmm.